# VBA Excel - Simplifiying For To function IF statements

Tags: vba, excel

I have a *Combo Box* (**GSMListType**) with different variables **"A", "A - K", "B", "C",** etc... linked to a *List Box* (**AvailableNumberList**) which calls on cells from different sheets based on the selection in the *Combo Box*.
The *Combo Box* has 32 different variables which call on 32 different sheets. Below is a sample of the code.

- "A" collects the data in sheet A_Regular and adds its items into the List Box
- "A - K" collects the data in sheet A_K and adds its items into the List Box
- "B" collects the data in sheet B_Regular and adds its items into the List Box
- "C" collects the data in sheet C_Regular and adds its items into the List Box
  and so on...

Is there a way to simplify the below mentioned code? The sheet is fully functional, but the code is a mess.

```
    Private Sub GSMListType_Change()
    Dim TypeLookup As Double
    'If listing has changed, clear AvailableNumberList and insert new data
    If GSMListType.ListIndex > -1 Then
    AvailableNumberList.Clear
    If GSMListType.Value = "A" Then
    TypeLookup = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(A_Regular.Range("A:E"), GSMListType.Value)
    With AvailableNumberList
        For k = 2 To TypeLookup + 1
            .AddItem A_Regular.Range("A" & k).Value
        Next k
    End With
    ElseIf GSMListType.Value = "A - K" Then
    TypeLookup = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(A_K.Range("A:E"), GSMListType.Value)
    With AvailableNumberList
        For k = 2 To TypeLookup + 1
            .AddItem A_K.Range("A" & k).Value
        Next k
    End With
    ElseIf GSMListType.Value = "B" Then
    TypeLookup = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(B_Regular.Range("A:E"), GSMListType.Value)
    With AvailableNumberList
        For k = 2 To TypeLookup + 1
            .AddItem B_Regular.Range("A" & k).Value
        Next k
    End With
    ElseIf GSMListType.Value = "C" Then
    TypeLookup = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(C_Regular.Range("A:E"), GSMListType.Value)
    With AvailableNumberList
        For k = 2 To TypeLookup + 1
            .AddItem C_Regular.Range("A" & k).Value
        Next k

.
.
.
    End With
    End If
    End If
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this improves your original code sample by any substantial measure but it does tidy things up by reducing the repetitious sections.

`Private Sub GSMListType_Change()
    Dim TypeLookup As Long, ws As Worksheet
    'If listing has changed, clear AvailableNumberList and insert new data
    If GSMListType.ListIndex > -1 Then
        With GSMListType
            Select Case .Value
                Case "A"
                    Set ws = A_Regular    'Sheets("A_Regular") ?????
                Case "A - K"
                    Set ws = A_K
                Case "B"
                    Set ws = B_Regular
                Case "C"
                    Set ws = C_Regular
                Case Else
                    'do nothing
            End Select
            TypeLookup = Application.CountIf(ws.Range("A:E"), .Value)
        End With
        With AvailableNumberList
            .Clear
            For k = 2 To TypeLookup + 1
                .AddItem ws.Range("A" & k).Value
            Next k
        End With
    End If
    Set ws = Nothing
End Sub`

I wasn't sure about your worksheet designation method to some module-wide variable pointing to the various worksheets so I includes a commented alternative that uses the worksheet name(s).